# How to show step while filling the form by using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I am making one web application.Registration form is quite large.So I want to show user the steps like(sep1,step2).How to handle in asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.wizard.aspx) control.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wizard control

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15804/ASP-NET-2-0-Wizard-Control

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/21/438732.aspx